# Why won't ternary operator work with redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, controller

I love the ternary operator. It really cleans up the code look, but I have a case where it won't behave correctly in a Rails controller.

I get a syntax error: `unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('`

I consistently get this issue, it light switches on changing the statement below to a ternary operator.  It always happens when I'm trying to use it in conjunction with a redirect statement.

Am I unaware of a rule about this?

```
if nexti==0 then
  redirect_to :back
else
  redirect_to edit_playt_path(id: actform['playt_id'], i: nexti)
end

nexti==0 ? redirect_to :back : redirect_to edit_playt_path(id: actform['playt_id'], i: nexti)
```

Comment: i think this has the same flaws, even if it does work,  you would still probably want parenthesis just for your own sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the implied nature of the hash

Ruby / Rails will imply your argument to redirect is a hash which has some awkward implications in your example

When ruby implies the arguments to redirect it sees it as a hash in the following scenario it is parsing it as

```
nexti==0 ? redirect_to({:back, : redirect_to edit_playt_path(id: actform['playt_id'], i: nexti})
```

which is invalid, it should work if you explicitly define your hash / argument

```
nexti==0 ? redirect_to(:back) : redirect_to(edit_playt_path({id: actform['playt_id'], i: nexti}))
```

most ruby / rails devs will tell you to avoid ternaries for reasons like this, and also general human comprehension of what is going on. Ruby was ment to be an expressive language, so embrace it.

```
return redirect_to(:back) if nexti==0
redirect_to(edit_playt_path({id: actform['playt_id'], i: nexti}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parentheses in your call to `redirect_to` so the parser can correctly understand what’s going on:

```
nexti==0 ? redirect_to(:back) : redirect_to(edit_playt_path(id: actform['playt_id'], i: nexti))
```